# Why I can't initialize object in the same manner (without using ref)?

Tags: c#, .net, out, ref

I would like to initialize an object of type `B` from another class `A`, why I still get null? Is it possible to do it without using `ref` and `out` modifiers?

```
    class A
    {
        public void Initialize(B value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = new B();
            }
        }
    }

    class B
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            B b = null;
            a.Initialize(b);
        }
    }
```

[upd.] I thought the `b` variable could be passed by `ref` because of it's the instance of the class.

Comment: Why do you *expect* anything else? Please read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, just make Initialize() a function:

```
class A
{
    public B Initialize(B value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = new B();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = null;
        b = a.Initialize(b);
    }
```

This is a good solution, the data flow is clearly visible. No surprises.

But otherwise, just use a `ref`  (not an `out`) : `public void Initialize(ref B value)` and call `a.Initialize(ref b);`

---

> I thought the b variable could be passed by ref because of it's the instance of the class.

To answer that you need very precise wording: `b` is *not* the instance of a class. `b` is a reference to an instance. Instances never have a name.

And `b` is treated just like a value type: the reference is passed by value to the method. Unless you use `ref`.

Comment: The `??` operator is handy here: `public B Initialize(B value) { return value ?? new B(); }` :)

Comment: @Guffa - I know but I went with minimal changes to the original code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanx for the explanation. I really lost sight of fact that "b is not the instance of a class. b is a reference to an instance".

Answer (score 1):

`public void Initialize(B value)`

Inside this method, `value` is just like a local variable, when you assign something to it,
the caller is not affected.

> Is it possible to do it without using ref and out modifiers?

No not in this manner, that's what ref/out is for.

You could just return the new object though, and assign it in the caller.

```
 public B Initialize() {
     return new B();
  }

... 
  b = a.Initialize();
```